# dice game is calculating the correct score

Tags: javascript

in javascript from a udemy course. i made a dice game.   the game works except the score is incorrect.     the score is the increment of the dice digits.  for example first for is 3. so score is 3. but its not i roll a three and the score is 9.

```js
var scores,roundScore,activePlayer,dice;
 scores       = [0,0];
 roundScore   = 0;
 activePlayer = 0;


 
  document.getElementById('score-0').textContent ='0';
  document.getElementById('score-1').textContent ='0';
  document.getElementById('current-0').textContent ='0';
  document.getElementById('current-1').textContent ='0';
  document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';



 document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dice = (Math.random() * Math.floor(6)) + 1;
  var diceDom  = document.querySelector('.dice');

  diceDom.style.display = 'block';
  diceDom.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';

  if(dice !== 1){
   //add score
   roundScore += dice;
   document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
  }else{ 
   //nextplayer
     activePlayer === 0 ? activePlayer = 1 : activePlayer = 0;
     roundScore = 0;

     document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0'; 
     document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';

     document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active');
     document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');
     document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';

     }
  



 });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4), rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4)), url(back.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.player-0-panel,
.player-1-panel {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 100px;
}



/**********************************************
*** PLAYERS
**********************************************/

.player-name {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.player-score {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.active { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.active .player-name { font-weight: 300; }

.active .player-name::after {
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    top: -7px;
    right: 10px;
    
}

.player-current-box {
    background-color: #EB4D4D;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.player-current-label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
}

.player-current-score {
    font-size: 30px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #555;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

button:hover { font-weight: 600; }
button:hover i { margin-right: 20px; }

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

i {
    color: #EB4D4D;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-top: -4px;
    transition: margin 0.3s;
}

.btn-new { top: 45px;}
.btn-roll { top: 403px;}
.btn-hold { top: 467px;}

.dice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 178px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

.winner { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.winner .player-name { font-weight: 300; color: #EB4D4D; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        
        <title>Pig Game</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="player-0-panel active">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-0">43</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-0">11</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="player-1-panel">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-1">72</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-1">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
            <button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
            <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>
            
            <img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice">
        </div>
        
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>




     <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> -->
</html>
```

[score 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPjPm.png)[i rolled a 4 but the score is 10 when it should be what the dice rolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmb7U.png)

Comment: `Math.floor(6)` is just `6`, you probably want to floor the whole expression

Comment: `var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

It should be 

`var dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;`

The issue is you have added 2 times the same script, that means you have added 2 times the click event, which in turn means you are adding the dice value twice to the score.

Remove the last script tag, line 47 in index.html. Just above html tag.

Comment: thats what i had orignally. thats how it is in the tutorial but the result is the same  incorrect score.     i tried several declartions and its all the same. such as 
var dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
vvar dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(6) + 1;

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have added 2 times the same script, that means you have added 2 times the click event, which in turn means you are adding the dice value twice to the score.

Remove the last script tag, line 47 in index.html. Just above html tag.

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much.   i was certain the error was in the js file and i never doubled check the html code.

Comment: i  1 up you but i have less then 15 reps

Comment: kool, didnt get you ? you can make my first comment as solution since have added the same solution there.

Comment: how do i choose your comment as solution?